# Master View Controller and Detail View Controller not found in Object Library

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode5, xcode-storyboard

In Xcode 5.0.2 when I create a new universal Master View iOS application and then look at the generated Main_iPhone.storyboard and the source code in *.m and .h files -

a lot of stuff seems to be created visually in the storyboard.

But I don't understand, where do the Master View Controller and Detail View Controller come from, I can not find them in the Object Library (on the right side of Xcode):

[image: screenshot]

So if I would create a blank new storyboard file - where would I find these 2 types of controllers, so that I could drag them into the storyboard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Master View controller is an instance of

```
@interface MasterViewController : UITableViewController
```

and therefore is a custom subclass of a "Table View Controller", and
the Detail View controller is an instance of

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController
```

and therefore a custom subclass of a "View Controller".

Comment: Yes, but when I create a new storyboard and drag a "Table View Controller" and a "View Controller" from the "Object Library" into it - then I don't see a "Detail View Controller" or "Master View Controller" as in the screenshot.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: You drag e.g. a "Table View Controller" and then set the "Custom Class" in the Identity inspector to the "DetailViewController" class (which you have to create before).